GEE - output from ImageCollection different for Sentinel S2 Harmonized in comparison to Sentinel S2
I'm trying to download an ImageCollection from the GEE via the Python API but i get different results when i use "COPERNICUS/S2_SR" and "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED" as ImageCollection.
I'm using the eemont package to extract a spectral time for an AOI.
My code looks like this:
S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED") \
.filterDate("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31") \
.filterBounds(mygeom) \
.maskClouds() \
.scaleAndOffset() \
.filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", "less_than", 30) \
.preprocess() \
.spectralIndices("NDVI") \
.select("NDVI")

The output looks like this:
ImageCollection COPERNICUS/S2_SR (28 elements)
type:ImageCollection
id:COPERNICUS/S2_SR
version:1728042384530311
bands: []
properties: Object (21 properties)
features: List (28 elements)
and it works just fine with this code:
S2_ts = S2.getTimeSeriesByRegions(
collection=mygeom,
bands= ["B4", "B8"],
reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale=20)
tsPandas = geemap.ee_to_df(S2_ts)

but when i try it with the harmonized ImageCollection:
S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED") \
.filterDate("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31") \
.filterBounds(mygeom) \
.maskClouds() \
.scaleAndOffset() \
.filterMetadata("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", "less_than", 30) \
.preprocess() \
.spectralIndices("NDVI") \
.select("NDVI")

the output looks like this: 
<ee.imagecollection.ImageCollection object at 0x00000249B610F460>
and the second code snippet doesn't work anymore.
It says that it has an Invalid type and expects a FeatureCollection.
additonal info
When i tried it with the TOA ImageCollection (COPERNIUS/S2_HARMONIZED) it worked just fine.
Is there another way to download the NDVI Values and store them in a df?
